# Can a LIRA system work with cjdns or other decentralized meshnets?

Tags: anonymity, cryptocurrency

[LIRA (Lightweight Incentivized Routing for Anonymity)](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~jansen/papers/lira-ndss2013.pdf) is a scheme to incentivize participants in Tor to contribute resources, in particular bandwidth.

The paper talks about it being used for Tor. Can it work for other decentralized and privacy-friendly networks as well, such as cjdns?